# Aligning nodes in dot with group does not give the desired result

Tags: graph, graphviz, state-machine, dot, finite-state-automaton

I tried to create graph from here [Improving graphviz layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2278030/improving-graphviz-layout) and want to get the exact picture
[image: 1]
like in post, but can't vertically align nodes and get nice curve in `q3->q3`. My question is about how fix this:
[image: 2]

```
digraph {
    layout=dot
    rankdir = LR
    
    node [shape=circle]
    
    Start [shape=plaintext group=g1]
    q0 [shape = doublecircle label=<<I>q</I><SUB>0</SUB>> group=g1]
    q1 [label=<<I>q</I><SUB>1</SUB>> group=g1]
    q2 [label=<<I>q</I><SUB>2</SUB>> group=g2]
    q3 [label=<<I>q</I><SUB>3</SUB>> group=g2]
    
    Start -> q0
    q0 -> q1 [label="1"]
    q1 -> q0 [label="0"]
    q1 -> q3 [label="0"]
    q3:s -> q3:e [label="0,1"]
    q0 -> q2 [label="1"]
    q2 -> q0 [label="0"]
    q2 -> q3 [label="1"]
    
    {rank = same; q2;q0;}
    {rank = same; q1;q3;}
}
```

[Online editor](http://magjac.com/graphviz-visual-editor/?dot=digraph%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20layout%3Ddot%0D%0A%09rankdir%20%3D%20LR%0D%0A%09%0D%0A%09node%20%5Bshape%3Dcircle%5D%0D%0A%09%0D%0A%09Start%20%5Bshape%3Dplaintext%20group%3Dg1%5D%0D%0A%09q0%20%5Bshape%20%3D%20doublecircle%20label%3D%3C%3CI%3Eq%3C%2FI%3E%3CSUB%3E0%3C%2FSUB%3E%3E%20group%3Dg1%5D%0D%0A%09q1%20%5Blabel%3D%3C%3CI%3Eq%3C%2FI%3E%3CSUB%3E1%3C%2FSUB%3E%3E%20group%3Dg1%5D%0D%0A%09q2%20%5Blabel%3D%3C%3CI%3Eq%3C%2FI%3E%3CSUB%3E2%3C%2FSUB%3E%3E%20group%3Dg2%5D%0D%0A%09q3%20%5Blabel%3D%3C%3CI%3Eq%3C%2FI%3E%3CSUB%3E3%3C%2FSUB%3E%3E%20group%3Dg2%5D%0D%0A%09%0D%0A%09Start%20-%3E%20q0%0D%0A%09q0%20-%3E%20q1%20%5Blabel%3D%221%22%5D%0D%0A%09q1%20-%3E%20q0%20%5Blabel%3D%220%22%5D%0D%0A%09q1%20-%3E%20q3%20%5Blabel%3D%220%22%5D%0D%0A%09q3%3As%20-%3E%20q3%3Ae%20%5Blabel%3D%220%2C1%22%5D%0D%0A%09q0%20-%3E%20q2%20%5Blabel%3D%221%22%5D%0D%0A%09q2%20-%3E%20q0%20%5Blabel%3D%220%22%5D%0D%0A%09q2%20-%3E%20q3%20%5Blabel%3D%221%22%5D%0D%0A%09%0D%0A%09%7Brank%20%3D%20same%3B%20q2%3Bq0%3B%7D%0D%0A%09%7Brank%20%3D%20same%3B%20q1%3Bq3%3B%7D%0D%0A%7D)

**P.S.** I came up with another variant, it's better than the first one, but not yet  what I visually expected:

```
digraph {
    layout=dot
    ranksep=0.2;
    
    node [shape=circle]
    
    Start [shape=plaintext group=g1]
    q0 [shape = doublecircle label=<<I>q</I><SUB>0</SUB>> group=g1]
    q1 [label=<<I>q</I><SUB>1</SUB>> group=g1]
    q2 [label=<<I>q</I><SUB>2</SUB>> group=g2]
    q3 [label=<<I>q</I><SUB>3</SUB>> group=g2]
    
    Start -> q0
    q0:ne -> q1:nw [label="1"]
    q1:sw -> q0:se [label="0"]
    q1 -> q3 [label="0"]
    q3:se -> q3:e [label="0,1";]
    q0 -> q2 [label="1"]
    q2 -> q0 [label="0"]
    q2 -> q3 [label="1"; constraint=false]
    
    {rank=same; Start; q0; q1}
    {rank=same; q2; q3}
    
    //hack starting
    //invisnode [shape=point, width=0]
    edge [style=invis]
    q0 -> q2
    //q0 -> invisnode -> q1
}
```

Result:
[image: 4]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Community What details do I need to provide?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Image:
[image: finite-state machine graph made by graphviz]
Script:

```
digraph {
    ranksep=1;
    nodesep=0.5;

    node [shape=circle]

    Start [margin=0 width=0 shape=plaintext]
    q0 [shape = doublecircle label=<<I>q</I><SUB>0</SUB>>]
    q1 [label=<<I>q</I><SUB>1</SUB>>]
    q2 [label=<<I>q</I><SUB>2</SUB>>]
    q3 [label=<<I>q</I><SUB>3</SUB>>]

    Start -> q0
    q1 -> q0 [xlabel="1"]
    q0 -> q1 [xlabel="0"]
    q1 -> q3 [label=" 0"]
    q3:se -> q3:e [label=" 0,1"]
    q2 -> q0 [xlabel="0 "]
    q0 -> q2 [xlabel="1 "]
    q2 -> q3 [label="1"]

    {rank=same; Start; q0; q1}
    {rank=same; q2; q3}
}
```

Answer's sources: [how `group` attribute works](https://forum.graphviz.org/t/how-to-align-nodes-using-a-group-attribute/1317/3), [solution](https://forum.graphviz.org/t/how-to-align-nodes-using-a-group-attribute/1317/4)

P.S. I think I can get a nice curve `q3->q3` using the `neato` engine with [`pos`](https://graphviz.org/docs/attrs/pos/) node attribute for positioning nodes and [`pos`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70378702/how-to-draw-a-spline-curve-between-2-points-with-a-control-points-with-graphviz) edge attribute for spline control points. Solution still in work.